# Pandas - Split by Numbers and Letters and save last split

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a `series` of strings in the format of:

```
12345678ABC
12345678ABCDEF
12345A6789AB
12A3456ABC
```

I would like to split only on the beginning of the trailing letters and output like so:

```
1  12345678       ABC
2  12345678       ABCDEF
3  12345A6789     AB
4  12A3456        ABC
```

- The preceeding 'number' string can contain some A-Z characters like 3&4.
- 'number' and 'letter' are of variable length (letter being capped at maximum of 6).

I tried to do `df['ID'].str.split('[a-zA-Z]')` with hopes to grab the last `-1` split but the output contains no letters. Hoping to complete this in pandas if possible without resorting to `re`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression with `Series.str.extract`, where your first capturing group is everything up to the last digit, and then the next capturing group is all of the letters remaining. I've added optional capturing groups so that it works if your string has all numbers or all letters.

```
s = pd.Series(['12345678ABC', '12345678ABCDEF', '12345A6789AB', 
               '12A3456ABC', '1234123', 'ABCDERED'])

s.str.extract('(?:(.*\d))?(?:([a-zA-Z]+))?')
```

Output:

```
            0         1
0    12345678       ABC
1    12345678    ABCDEF
2  12345A6789        AB
3     12A3456       ABC
4     1234123       NaN
5         NaN  ABCDERED
```

Comment: Phenomenal, very succinct.. thought this was possible :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Let A be the array containing strings
# Let nA be the seperated string array
# Let pA be the prefix array
for i in A:
    t = -1
    for index, character in enumerate(i[::-1]):
        if character.isdigit():
            t = index + 1
            break
    nA.append(i[t:])
    pA.append(i[:t])
for index, i in enumerate(A):
    print(pA[index], ' ', nA[index])
```